# VBA creating textfiles in a loop from a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, export, text-files

I'm trying to create a loop to process multiple excel files and create for every excel file text-files. I've came a long way but I ran into an error.

I have three pieces of code: 1) a loop, 2) some calculations 3) creation of text-files. Separate from eachother they work like a charm, but when I put them togehter in a single sub (as displayed in the Loop below) I get "Bad file mode (Error 54)" for the command [Print #1, Left$(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1) ' strString] when creating the text-file. I can't figure out why there is a conflict between the different codes.

The loop is as

```
Sub GEF_Processor()
Dim i As Integer
Dim fd As FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
End With

For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    addNewWorkBook (fd.SelectedItems.Item(i))
    Call macro3
Next i

Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

The creating of the text files goes like

```
Sub macro3()

Dim hndFile                                           As Long
Dim intColumn                                         As Integer
Dim intLast_Column                                    As Integer
Dim lngLast_Row                                       As Long
Dim lngRow                                            As Long
Dim strOutput                                         As String


intLast_Column = Worksheets("CPT_DEL_AFT").UsedRange.Column - 1 +     Worksheets("CPT_DEL_AFT").UsedRange.Columns.Count
lngLast_Row =  Worksheets("CPT_DEL_AFT").UsedRange.Rows(Worksheets("CPT_DEL_AFT").UsedRange.Row s.Count).Row

hndFile = FreeFile

Open "-DEL_AFT.gef" For Output As hndFile

For lngRow = 1& To lngLast_Row

  strOutput = ""

  For intColumn = 1 To intLast_Column
      strOutput = strOutput & Worksheets("CPT_DEL_AFT").Cells(lngRow, intColumn).Value & "  "
  Next intColumn

  If Len(Trim$(Replace(strOutput, ";", ""))) > 0 Then
     Print hndFile, Left$(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1) ' strString
  End If

Next lngRow

Close #hndFile
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `strName` defined?  I would suggest you use `Option Explicit`.

Comment: Why are you using `Print #1 ... ` instead of `Print hndFile`? Also, you probably want to assign `hndFile = FreeFile` *inside* the loop (assuming each iteration needs to be a new file).

Comment: The `strName` is defined somewhere else, I left this out for readibility... Thanks for your reply. I tried your sugestion but another error pops up... `Compile error: Method not valid without suitable object` I find it very strange that I can run the files seperate form eachother...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bit of inconsistency in your code, you are using hndFile to create the file and #1 to Print to it:

```
Open strName & "-DEL_AFT.gef" For Output As hndFile
```

And:

```
Print #1, Left$(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
```

Change the Print statement to the following to maintain consistency:

```
Print #hndFile, Left$(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the adjustment but another error pops up `Compile error: Method not valid without suitable object` ... I find it very strange that I can run the files seperate from eachother succesfully...

Comment: I apologize, I missed the required # symbol see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, It worked! Thank you very much! Should have been able to figure that out for my self, excuse me for my laziness...